# Android programm doesnt want to open on whole screen

Tags: android, apk, resolution

Just created apk yesterday:)

[image]

it doesnt open on the whole screen! can you help by telling why?  I tried on virtual one it fitted all screen...

Comment: may be you have margins set in the xml layout

Comment: put the layout xml structure

Comment: Can you paste your code, which specifies the application need to appear in full screen.

Comment: Just a guess: You want your components to fill the whole screen (the whitespace to the bottom and the right)? Then the question title is misleading as this is not what "full screen" normally means in this context (no title/status bar).

Comment: As His says, your heading means you don't need to use the whole screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this one line before `setContentView`

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
//setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
```

And if you want full screen then use below code:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
//setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
```

Yeah, This one also. Just put `theme` on `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
   android:name="MainActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this lines in your **manifest** file

```
    <activity
        android:name="activity name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
```

also use layout.xml like this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/top_home" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/about_back_selector"
        android:onClick="@string/back_click"
        android:text="@string/back"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/logo"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top"
    android:background="@drawable/payment_bg" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/titleedit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:hint="لقب"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/feedbackedit"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#11116F"
        android:textColorHint="#444141"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/feedbackedit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleedit"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:hint="التغذية الاسترجاعية"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/usermailedit"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#11116F"
        android:textColorHint="#444141"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usermailedit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/feedbackedit"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:hint="البريد الإلكتروني"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#11116F"
        android:textColorHint="#444141"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/usermailedit"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:onClick="@string/send"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:text="حفظ"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you set your layout container width to match_parent or fill_parent ?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your questions is not clear enough for folks to answer. can you pls clarify your question